# Does a woman HAVE to get married?

Tags: nikah, women

In this life, does a Muslim woman HAVE to get married or can she stay single her whole life especially since she hasn't found someone compatible to marry? What does Islam say about women and marriage?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Islam is a strong advocate of marriage.Unlike the Roman Catholic priests and nuns, Celibacy is not allowed in Islam. The prophet (pbuh) has said:

> "There is no celibacy in Islam."

In Mawaahib al-Jaleel it was said:

> “Marriage is obligatory for a woman who is unable to feed or clothe
>   herself unless she gets married.”

In al-Sharh al-Kabeer, concerning obligatory marriage it says:

> “If a person fears that he may commit fornication, it (marriage) is
>   obligatory on him.”

In Fath al-Wahhaab, it says:

> “For the woman who has (physical) desires, marriage is sunnah, just as
>   it is for the one who needs maintenance and the one who fears being
>   taken advantage of by immoral persons.”

Thus, any Muslim should not avoid marriage until and unless they have no other choice other than to wait.

Comment: This is a really good answer. Marriage can literally take 4 forms: haram, disliked, sunnah, and obligatory all depending on the circumstances and the individual himself.

Answer (score -3):

Women do not have obligation to get married.

1. there's no mention of such obligation in Quran
2. assuming there's an obligation of such, but since you cannot find one suitable so you'd be unable to fulfil the obligation, so there's no wrong on you.